# Рисование дерева в Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, бинарное-дерево

у меня проблема с AutoScroll и рисованием (суть вопроса после кода). Я вот по такому коду рисую AVL- дерево:

```
namespace AVL
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        RandomFill rand;
        List<int> list;
        const int SIZE = 25;
        const int WIDTH = 30;
        const int HEIGHT = 30;
        Font dataFont = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, HEIGHT / 2, FontStyle.Bold);
        AVL tr = new AVL();
        List<Point> pointList = new List<Point>(0);
        List<int> dataList = new List<int>(0);
        public Form1()
        {
            rand = new RandomFill(SIZE);
            list = rand.GetRandomFilledList();
            InitializeComponent();
            for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
            {
                tr.Add(list[i]);
            }

        }
        public void DisplayTree(AVL.Node root, Graphics graph, Pen pen, List<Point> pointList, List<int> dataList)
        {
            DrawConnectingines(root, graph, pen);
            for (int i = 0; i < pointList.Count; i++)
            {
                graph.DrawEllipse(pen, pointList[i].X, pointList[i].Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                graph.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, pointList[i].X, pointList[i].Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                graph.DrawString(dataList[i].ToString(), dataFont, Brushes.Black, pointList[i].X, pointList[i].Y);
            }
        }
        private void DrawConnectingines(AVL.Node root, Graphics graph, Pen pen)
        {
            if (root.left != null)
            {
                graph.DrawLine(pen, root.point.X + WIDTH/2, root.point.Y + HEIGHT/2, root.left.point.X + WIDTH / 2, root.left.point.Y + HEIGHT / 2);
                DrawConnectingines(root.left, graph, pen);
            }
            if (root.right != null)
            {
                graph.DrawLine(pen, root.point.X + WIDTH / 2, root.point.Y + HEIGHT / 2, root.right.point.X + WIDTH / 2, root.right.point.Y + HEIGHT / 2);
                DrawConnectingines(root.right, graph, pen);
            }
        }
        private void PushNodesInList(AVL.Node root, List<Point> pointList, List<int> dataList)
        {
            if (root.left != null)
            {
                PushNodesInList(root.left, pointList, dataList);
            }
            root.point.X = (WIDTH + WIDTH) * pointList.Count;
            root.point.Y = (HEIGHT + HEIGHT) * root.level;
            pointList.Add(root.point);
            dataList.Add(root.data);
            if (root.right != null)
            {
                PushNodesInList(root.right, pointList, dataList);
            }
        }

        private void treePanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics graph = e.Graphics;
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
            //рисование 
            tr.RecountDepth();
            DisplayTree(tr.GetRoot(), graph, pen, pointList, dataList);

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pointList.Clear();
            dataList.Clear();
            PushNodesInList(tr.GetRoot(), pointList, dataList);
            treePanel.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

**Проблема в том, что если дерево не влезает в treePanel, то нужен Scroll рисунка, но как его реализовать, я не знаю. Свойство AutoScroll у treePanel работает только если я вместо рисования кругов рисую Label-метки, но даже в этом случае рисунок как-то странно съезжает, т.е. проблему это не решает (наверное)**

Помогите, пожалуйста кодом или советом!)
[image: Вот такая галимотья, при скролле]
[image: Вот так выходит сейчас, но нужно, чтобы при скролле было также и справа]

1-изображение - это нужно устранить
2-изображение - А вот так пока получается, но нужно , чтобы можно было скроллить
  После ответа ниже - понял, что делал неправильно, код будет примерно следующий (линии я пока не нарисовал, но скроллящееся дерево без соединительных линий - уже есть)
Вот обновлённый код:

```
namespace AVL
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //GraphicsPath
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath myPath;
        //
        RandomFill rand;
        List<int> list;
        const int SIZE = 25;
        const int WIDTH = 30;
        const int HEIGHT = 30;
        Font dataFont = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, HEIGHT / 2, FontStyle.Bold);
        AVL tree = new AVL();
        List<Point> pointList = new List<Point>(0);
        List<int> dataList = new List<int>(0);
        public Form1()
        {
            //на замену предыдущему способу - GraphicsPath!
            myPath = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
            //
            rand = new RandomFill(SIZE);
            list = rand.GetRandomFilledList();
            InitializeComponent();
            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            {
                tree.Add(list[i]);
            }
        }
        private void treePanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            pointList.Clear();
            dataList.Clear();
            tree.RecountDepth();
            PushNodesInList(tree.GetRoot(), pointList, dataList);

        }
        public void DisplayTree(AVL.Node root, Graphics graph, Pen pen, List<Point> pointList, List<int> dataList)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < pointList.Count; i++)
            {
                myPath.AddEllipse(pointList[i].X, pointList[i].Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            }
        }

        private void PushNodesInList(AVL.Node root, List<Point> pointList, List<int> dataList)
        {
            if (root.left != null)
            {
                PushNodesInList(root.left, pointList, dataList);
            }
            root.point.X = (WIDTH + WIDTH) * pointList.Count + delta * WIDTH;
            root.point.Y = (HEIGHT + HEIGHT) * root.level;
            pointList.Add(root.point);
            dataList.Add(root.data);
            if (root.right != null)
            {
                PushNodesInList(root.right, pointList, dataList);
            }
        }
        private void CheckForScroll(AVL.Node root)
        { //Нужна для расширения panel1, которая есть наше дерево. Если не помещается дерево - panel1 расширится и на panel2 должен появиться скроллбар.
            int treePanelCurrentWidth = panel1.Width;
            if (root.right != null)
            {
                CheckForScroll(root.right);
            }
            if (root.right == null && root.point.X > treePanelCurrentWidth)
            {
                panel1.Width = root.point.X + WIDTH;
            }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckForScroll(tree.GetRoot()); 
            panel1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            panel1.Region = new Region(myPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала проясним ошибочное предположение: нарисованное изображение не является контентом, с точки зрения `ScrolableControl`, от которого наследуются все контролы, которые поддерживают скроллинг. Таким образом, свойство `AutoScroll` не может вам помочь, так как учитывает только вложенные контролы. Даже принудительная ручная активация скролла вам в данном случае не поможет.

---

Какие есть варианты? Основных три. Остальные - производные.

1. Так как скролл учитывает только контролы, то строить изображение с помощью кастомных контролов. Через свойство `Control.Region` можно придать контролу любую форму (вершина, ребро, да хоть весь граф).
2. Использовать двухслойную модель контрола, т.е. за скролл отвечает один, а рисуем на другом, вложенном в первый. При этом во время рисования не забываем изменять размер контрола на котором рисуем так, чтобы изображение умещалось полностью, тогда, как только вложенный контрол перестанет умещаться в родительском, активируется автоскролл и появится возможность прокрутки.
3. Берем скрол полностью в свои руки, исключив все автоматические рюшечки. Фактически, мы просто добавляем полосы скролла и с их помощью управляем положением изображения вручную. Для этого изображение целиком должно быть представлено объектом `GraphicsPath`, для которого можно задать позиционирование при отрисовке.

Если нужна только картинка, я бы предпочел последний вариант. Для интерактива - без вариантов первый. Второй - как переходный от вашего решения к любому более специализированному.

---

Пока как-то так.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помог первый вариант в купе с 3-им. Я сейчас переделываю, получилось создать панель, которая "делает регионом" graphicPath. И эту самую панель я поместил на другую панель, у которой уже есть AutoScroll.